# How to use SetWindowsHookEx to capture specific widget in Chrome?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, winapi, visual-c++

I need to get the rect of  a specific page widget in Chrome, so I used SetWindowsHookEx. And when I get the hwnd of the specific page through title name, and get its process and thread id, and use SetWindowsHookEx to capture its rect and show a messagebox and write in file. But what confuses me are two things.

1. When I really have a Widget name as "Google - Google Chrome", all the widgets in Chrome, that when I move everyone of them, there shows a message box, and my file has been written theirs rect.

   (Widget, I don't know how to descrive it clearly, One widget have lots of pages, chrome have lots of widget, one widget is one process)
2. When I have no widget named "Google - Google Chrome", there pid and tid is both 0, but when I move any widget , there shows a messagebox and my file has been written. As the msdn shows, if the tid is zero, all the 64-bit programs should have all the actions.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;

    HMODULE hdll = LoadLibrary(L"Dll1.dll");
    
    HOOKPROC hproc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hdll, "CallWndRefProc");
    int a = GetLastError();
    std::cout <<"error: "<<  a << std::endl;
    HWND hwnd=FindWindow(NULL, L"ssss - Google Chrome");
    DWORD pid = 0;
    DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, hproc, hdll, tid);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    //for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    //  Sleep(2000);
    //}
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndRefProc(__in int nCode, __in WPARAM wParam, __in LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (NULL != lParam) {
        if (nCode == HCBT_MOVESIZE) {
            RECT *rect = (RECT *)lParam;
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT(""), TEXT("Tips"), MB_OK);
            FILE *file;
            fopen_s(&file, "F:\\hooklog.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(file, "Move or size (%d, %d, %d, %d) for target window.\n", rect->left, rect->right, rect->top, rect->bottom);
            fprintf(file, "lParam(%d)", wParam);
            fclose(file);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Now I found that, in case one, I try create two wdiget in chrome, but its pid and tid are both same? Why? If theirs pid are same, why in my Task Manager there are lots of chrome?

And in case 2, I found that my IDE-VS2017 has no action, because it's 32-bit. But FireFox and chrome all hava that action, so it explains that.

Now, are all widgets in chrome have one pid and tid? are they all in one process? In this case, how can I get specific widget's rect?

Comment: instead call `SetWindowsHookEx` use `SetWinEventHook`

Comment: @RbMm I think it shoud not work, cause all the windows in Chrome all have the same threadId, so is there any method to use hwnd to set hook?

Comment: Chrome (and most current frameworks) don't use separate HWNDs for each widget.  Chrome has one HWND for the top-level window and that's it.   You can use [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) to display the window tree.